# Complex MySQL query problems and also SQL hangs

Tags: mysql, freeze

I am trying to write an SQL query which is pretty complex.  The requirements are as follows:

I need to return these fields from the query:

```
track.artist
track.title
track.seconds
track.track_id
track.relative_file
album.image_file
album.album
album.album_id
track.track_number
```

I can select a random track with the following query:

```
select 
  track.artist, track.title, track.seconds, track.track_id, 
  track.relative_file, album.image_file, album.album, 
  album.album_id, track.track_number 
FROM 
  track, album 
WHERE 
  album.album_id = track.album_id 
ORDER BY RAND() limit 10;
```

Here is where I am having trouble though.  I also have a table called "trackfilters1" thru "trackfilters10"  Each row has an auto incrementing ID field.  Therefore, row 10 is data for album_id 10.  These fields are populated with 1's and 0's.  For example, album #10 has 10 tracks, then trackfilters1.flags will contain "1111111111" if all tracks are to be included in the search.  If track 10 was to be excluded, then it would contain "1111111110"

My problem is including this clause.

The latest query I have come up with is the following:

```
select 
  track.artist, track.title, track.seconds, 
  track.track_id, track.relative_file, album.image_file, 
  album.album, album.album_id, track.track_number 
FROM 
  track, album, trackfilters1, trackfilters2 
WHERE 
  album.album_id = track.album_id 
AND 
  ( (album.album_id = trackfilters1.id) 
OR 
    (album.album_id=trackfilters2.id) ) 
AND 
  ( (mid(trackfilters1.flags, track.track_number,1) = 1) 
OR 
  ( mid(trackfilters2.flags, track.track_number,1) = 1)) 
ORDER BY RAND() limit 2;
```

however this is causing SQL to hang.  I'm presuming that I'm doing something wrong.  Does anybody know what it is?   I would be open to suggestions if there is an easier way to achieve my end result, I am not set on repairing my broken query if there is a better way to accomplish this.

Additionally, in my trials, I have noticed when I had a working query and added say, trackfilters2 to the FROM clause without using it anywhere in the query, it would hang as well.  This makes me wonder.  Is this correct behavior?  I would think adding to the FROM list without making use of the data would just make the server procure more data, I wouldn't have expected it to hang.

Comment: _“then trackfilters1.flags will contain "1111111111" if all tracks are to be included in the search. If track 10 was to be excluded, then it would contain "1111111110"”_ – that sounds like a really bad database design. You should normalize.

Comment: It is because when you just use two tables separated by comma you are doing cross product,i.e., each row of one table join with every other row of another table.So when you include trackfilters2,but doesn't use it in where clause,your system will eventually hang due to cross product

Comment: Perhaps I can have a look at some mathematical computation.  I had a thought to do something similar that of CHMOD figures in linux where you can use a 3 digit number to determine 9 positions which could have 1 of 3 states (rwxrwxrwx) but thought this would be a more logical approach as I could use MID to pull out the position of the track number within the query.  I wonder if this is similar to your suggestion.  I will have a read right now on normalization.  Thanks for replying

Comment: At least make a minimal effort to format your SQL so it's readable. A space here and there and use of the ENTER key makes a world of difference, both to others when they're trying to read that mess and to people who have to try to maintain it later. SQL editors don't charge for using either of those keys on the keyboard. If you don't want to format it in your own use, fine; at least have the courtesy to do it here when you're asking us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information here to determine what's causing the performance issue.

But here's a few suggestions and comments.

Ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operations, and use the JOIN keyword instead. And relocate the join predicates to an ON clause.

And for heaven's sake, format the SQL so that it's decipherable by someone trying to read it.

There's some questions here... will there always be a matching row in both trackfilters1 and trackfilters2 for rows you want to return? Or could a row be missing from trackfilters2, and you still want to return the row if there's a matching row in trackfilters1?  (The answer to that question determines whether you'd want to use an outer join vs an inner join to those tables.)

For best performance with large sets, having appropriate indexes defined is going to be critical.

Use **`EXPLAIN`** to see the execution plan.

I suggest you try writing your query like this:

```
  SELECT track.artist
       , track.title
       , track.seconds
       , track.track_id
       , track.relative_file
       , album.image_file
       , album.album
       , album.album_id
       , track.track_number
    FROM track
    JOIN album
      ON album.album_id = track.album_id
    LEFT
    JOIN trackfilters1
      ON trackfilters1.id = album.album_id
    LEFT
    JOIN trackfilters2
      ON trackfilters2.id = album.album_id
   WHERE MID(trackfilters1.flags, track.track_number, 1) = '1' 
      OR MID(trackfilters2.flags, track.track_number, 1) = '1'
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 2
```

And if you want help with performance, provide the output from EXPLAIN, and what indexes are defined.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to write that response.  I've got a lot to learn about joins, inner and outer etc.  I've decided to go with a different approach where I'll have a column "filterflags" for each entry in the TRACK table and it will be 10 digits (one for each track filter list)  From here I will be able to easily check mid(filterflags,x,1) for a 1 or a 0 within my queries and can do my queries as such.  I will be coming back to this post to take note of your suggests and try to understand them.  I'll accept your solve since you took the time to write this.Thanks everybody.